# Installing java 8 on ubuntu 14.04 ppa not adding

Tags: 14.04, java

I am trying to install `java8` on ubuntu server version 14.04.

I am trying:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
```

and I get:

> Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:webupd8team/java'. Please check that the PPA name
>   or format is correct.

It works on `ubuntu 16.04`.

Comment: I just checked that the ppa repository is available for Ubuntu 14.04 so it must be a typo error or a circumstantial connection problem. Try adding ppa:webupd8team/java from the software source window

Comment: what is the software source window?

Comment: Or try again, works here to add on 14.04

Comment: I tried a lot of times.. didn't work. This did though.. 
https://tecadmin.net/install-java-8-on-debian

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how it will be said in English. There is an application for managing software sources. This has a tab to add repositories manually[image]

Comment: i am on ubuntu server.. not on desktop, so how can i do that on the server.